# AucTeX: can I hide comments?

Tags: latex, auctex, code-folding

Is there a setting  in `auctex` that can hide (fold) comments (paragraphs which start with `%`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `TeX-fold-comment` (`C-c C-o C-c)` to hide the comment.  You need to enable `TeX-fold-mode` to make use of this functionality.

See the [AUCTeX manual on folding macros and environments](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Folding.html) for more information.

Comment: Can it be applied for the complete buffer?